# Rational Maps from Scheme to Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, affine-schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $\Bbbk$ be a field and $X$ a smooth scheme over $\Bbbk$.

If $X$ were a <strike>variety</strike> complex, smooth, projective variety, then I'd know that for fixed $n\in\Bbb N$, all rational maps $X\dashrightarrow\Bbb P^n_\Bbbk$ are all given by some choice of a line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$ and a $\Bbbk$-vector subspace $V\subseteq \mathcal L(X)$ of dimension $n+1$ such that the base locus of this linear system is of codimension at least two in $X$. This is, for example, in Griffiths & Harris, Chapter 4.

Is (something like) this still true if $X$ is any scheme over $\Bbbk$? Can anyone point me to a reference for this statement? I cannot seem to find it in any textbook on algebraic geometry that I checked.

PS: In my case, $X$ is actually just the spectrum of a regular local ring over $\Bbbk=\Bbb C$, in which case I am rather confident it will be true. I would still like to know how general this fact is.

Comment: If $X$ is an arbitrary scheme, what exactly do you mean by rational map? A morphism defined on a dense open set?

Comment: I am sceptical about the claim for varieties as written. For example if $X$ is a nodal rational curve then it has a rational map $X \dashrightarrow \mathbf P^1$ but there is no way to extend this across the node. So the associated linear system must have base locus of codim 1. Do G&H include some extra conditions in the word "variety"?

Comment: @Mohan, yes - an equivalence class of such morphisms to be precise. I am using Görtz-Wedhorn as my reference here, 9.6.

Comment: @Nefertiti: Yes sorry, that was a bit sloppy, $X$ should definitely be smooth. G&H do it for the complex projective smooth case only, i.e. $X$ is a manifold.

Comment: To address the question, I think the same statement should be true when $X$ is a normal, integral, Noetherian scheme. I can try to give the details if you like, but not right at the moment.

Comment: @Nefertiti: Thanks! I'd be grateful for details, but I would even *more* prefer a literature reference, in case that is easy to come by.